# JavaScript/HTML: find longest word and compare to current word

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a code that :

1. Allow my user to type in a sentence.
2. Find the longest word in that sentence.
3. Compare that longest one to every word in the sentence.
4. The words of the string directly out to a webpage, laid out so that no
   single line is longer than the longest word in the string.

I've been working this code for two days and feel like completely lost in somewhere. Please advise me to improve my code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Wrap Text </title>
    <script>
    
//Determine Longest word and compare to currend word       
    function longWord(string){  
        var lengthOfString = 0;
        var arrayOfText = string.split(" ");  
        for ( i = 0; i < arrayOfText.length; i++){
            if (arrayOfText[i].length > lengthofString){
                lengthOfString = arrayOfText[i].length;
            }
        }
        return lengthOfString;
        } 
       
// Longest vs current word
    function layoutString(string, length){
    var x = 0;
    var testLength = 0;
    var testLength = arrayOfText[i].length;
        do {
            testLength + 1 + arrayOfText[i].length
        } while (testLength > longWord);
    }

//Call this function in HTML               
    function wrapText(string) {
     var length = longWord(string);
        layoutString(string, length);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += arrayOfText + "<br>";
    }
   
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Let's Wrap your text!</h3>
<!--User Input Section-->    
    <p>Enter Text: <input id="yourValue" value=""></p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
<!--Button executing function-->    
<button onclick="wrapText(yourValue.value)">Wrap Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `lengthofString` is not same as `lengthOfString`. Please correct your code first and make it runnable.

Comment: Not sure what's your 4th requirement . Please explain

Comment: @ShrihariBalasubramani for example, if the longest word has 6 characters then all lines should be displayed less than or equal to 6 characters including space. Is this clear enough?

Comment: @31piy Thank you I fixed it

Comment: If possible then share Input and Expected output

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

1. arrayOfText is not accessible in layoutString and wrapText as it is a locale variable of longWord
2. In layoutString you use longWord (the function name) instead of the parameter length.
3. The line "testLength + 1 + arrayOfText[i].length" has no effect, it just adds the three values together but does not assign it to anything.
4. layoutString generally does nothing ...

I'm not sure about your 4th requirement as all words' length will be less or equal than the longest word's length, so I add hyphens in front of all shorter words so they are all the same length. Maybe that gets you closer to your final goal.

Try this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Wrap Text </title>
    <script>
    
    //Determine Longest word and compare to current word       
    function longWord(string){  
        var lengthOfString = 0;
        var arrayOfText = string.split(" ");  

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfText.length; i++){
            if (arrayOfText[i].length > lengthOfString){
                lengthOfString = arrayOfText[i].length;
            }
        }

        return lengthOfString;
     } 
       
    // Longest vs current word
    function layoutString(string, length){

        var arrayOfText = string.split(" ");  

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfText.length; i++){
            while (arrayOfText[i].length < length) {
                arrayOfText[i] = '-' + arrayOfText[i];
            };
        }

        return arrayOfText;
    }

    //Call this function in HTML               
    function wrapText(string) {
        var longestWordLength = longWord(string),
            strings = layoutString(string, longestWordLength),
            demo = document.getElementById("demo");

        demo.innerHTML = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
            demo.innerHTML += strings[i] + "<br>";
        }
    }
   
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Let's Wrap your text!</h3>
<!--User Input Section-->    
    <p>Enter Text: <input id="yourValue" value=""></p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
<!--Button executing function-->    
<button onclick="wrapText(yourValue.value)">Wrap Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```